# Put label next to input form

Tags: forms, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

I am working with bootstrap and laravel (blade) as backend and cant upload my code in jdfiddle to show. But the problem is that the label is far from the input box, is a way to put it next to it in the center ?

[image]

```
<div class="row">
         {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/insertHV', 'method' => 'POST')) }}
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">


    <label class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 control-label">Dato: </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                      {{ Form::text('Date', $date, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 text-left-imp"> 


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 control-label">Tid: </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                      {{ Form::text('Time', $time, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    </div>
                </div>


    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is a great example of how bootstrap is making things much more complicated then they need to be.

Comment: In html forms use fieldset (legend) for grouping widgets. it is looks better than 'div', imo, and screen readers understand it. p.s. i use 'fieldset' outside of forms for grouping widgets as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your labels have class `col-md-6`, which is going to make them pretty wide.  I'd try any of the following:

- Use a smaller label column, maybe `col-md-3`
- Use `text-align: right` inside the labels to push them next to inputs
- Try using `form-inline` or `form-horizontal` and see if it gives you what you want

This is the markup used in the [API sample](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) for the `form-horizontal` class (note how the elements are arranged):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```